# How to access minikube dashboard from external browser, deployed on gcloud compute engine

Tags: docker, networking, kubernetes, gcloud, minikube

I created an ubuntu instance on gcloud and installed minikube and all the required dependency in it.
Now I can do curl from gnode terminal "curl [http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/http:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/"](http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/http:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/%22) I get the HTML response back.

But I want to Access this URL from my Laptop browser.
I tried opening these Ports in
firewall of instance-node tcp:8080,8085,443,80,8005,8006,8007,8009,8009,8010,7990,7992,7993,7946,4789,2376,2377

But still unable to access the above mentioned url while replacing it with my **external(39.103.89.09) IP**
i.e http://39.103.89.09:8080/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/http:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

I believe I need to do some networking related changes but don't know what.

I am very new to Cloud computing and networking so please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that minikube binds to the VM's localhost interface making it inaccessible from a remote machine.

There may be a way to run minikube such that it binds to `0.0.0.0` and then you may be able to use it remotely.

Alternatively, you can keep the firewall limited to e.g. `22` and use SSH to port-forward the VM's port `8080` to your localhost. `gcloud' includes a helper for this too:

1. Ensure minikube is running on the VM
2. `gcloud compute ssh ${INSTANCE} --project=${PROJECT} --zone=${ZONE} --ssh-flag="-L 8080:localhost:8080"`
3. Try accessing Kubernetes endpoints from your **local** machine using `localhost:8080/api/v1/...`

#### Update

OK, I created a Debian VM (`n1-instance-2`), installed `docker` and `minikube`.

SSH'd into the instance:

```sh
gcloud compute ssh ${INSTANCE} \
--zone=${ZONE} \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

Then `minikube start`

Then:

```sh
minikube kubectl -- get namespaces
NAME              STATUS   AGE
default           Active   14s
kube-node-lease   Active   16s
kube-public       Active   16s
kube-system       Active   16s
```

minikube appears (I'm unfamiliar it) to run as a Docker container called `minikube` and it exposes 4 ports to the VM's (!) localhost: `22`,`2376`,`5000`,`8443`. The latter is key.

To determine the port mapping, either eyeball it:

```sh
docker container ls \
--filter=name=minikube \
--format="{{.Ports}}" \
| tr , \\n
```

Returns something like:

```
127.0.0.1:32771->22/tcp
127.0.0.1:32770->2376/tcp
127.0.0.1:32769->5000/tcp
127.0.0.1:32768->8443/tcp
```

In this case, the port we're interested in is `32768`

Or:

```sh
docker container inspect minikube \
--format="{{ (index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports \"8443/tcp\") 0).HostPort }}"
32768
```

Then, exit the shell and return using `--ssh-flag`:

```sh
gcloud compute ssh ${INSTANCE} \
--zone=${ZONE} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--ssh-flag="-L 8443:localhost:32768"
```

> **NOTE** `8443` will be the port on the localhost; `32768` is the remote minikube port

Then, from another shell on your local machine (and while the port-forwarding `ssh` continues in the other shell), pull the `ca.crt`, `client.key` and `client.crt`:

```sh
gcloud compute scp \
$(whoami)@${INSTANCE}:./.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.* \
${PWD} \
--zone=${ZONE} \
--project=${PROJECT} 

gcloud compute scp \
$(whoami)@${INSTANCE}:./.minikube/ca.crt \
${PWD} \
--zone=${ZONE} \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

Now, create a config file, call it `kubeconfig`:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: ./ca.crt
    server: https://localhost:8443
  name: minikube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: minikube
    user: minikube
  name: minikube
current-context: minikube
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: minikube
  user:
    client-certificate: ./client.crt
    client-key: ./client.key
```

And, lastly:

```sh
KUBECONFIG=./kubeconfig kubectl get namespaces
```

Should yield:

```
NAME              STATUS   AGE
default           Active   23m
kube-node-lease   Active   23m
kube-public       Active   23m
kube-system       Active   23m
```

Comment: Thanks  for you reply @DazWilkin, I tried the same but still not able to access the link. Getting error  "channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused". I also tried allowing TCP connection  from host sshd_config file but still not able to access it.

Comment: There you go! Try that. I was compelled to try it for myself and it works using the above instructions.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your time and help. I followed your step and it worked as you mentioned. But I was not able to access the url from the browser. To Access it from the browser I had to run one more command on google instance:- kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-system-anonymous --clusterrole=cluster-admin --user=system:anonymous   and now I am able access the UI on my local browser as well. Thanks